# Prometheus Node Exporter doesn't collect node_systemd_unit_state metric in minikube

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, minikube, prometheus-node-exporter

I've configured Prometheus Node Exporter to monitor my system, including enabling the systemd collector by adding --collector.systemd to the extraArgs in the Helm chart configuration. However, after deploying the changes, I'm unable to find the node_systemd_unit_state metric in the Prometheus UI.

Here's the relevant part of my prometheus-node-exporter configuration in the Helm chart values file:

```
prometheus-node-exporter:
 enabled: true
 extraArgs: ["--collector.systemd"]
 rbac:
    pspEnabled: false
 containerSecurityContext:
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

I am new to Prometheus and minikube and can't understand what I am missing here. Everything look normal. Node exporter configuration took from official prometheus-community [documentation](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus).